# Custom view attribute how to check is it selector or drawable

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-drawable, android-selector, android-custom-attributes

One of my custom view attribute is:

```
<attr name="socialViewAndroid_iconSrc" format="reference"/>
```

I need to check whether it is selector or direct icon drawable.

Passing selector:

```
app:socialViewAndroid_iconSrc="@drawable/selector"
```

Or passing icon drawable:

```
app:socialViewAndroid_iconSrc="@drawable/icon_drawable"
```

In custom view constructor:

```
mIconSrc = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.LikeViewHorizontal_socialViewAndroid_iconSrc, -1);
```

Now I need to know is `mIconSrc` a selector or icon drawable.

Comment: use `a.getDrawable()`

Comment: Would you please elaborate ? After getting drawable object what to do ?